# How to use function returned value in the same where clause of a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following tables like below :

```
Employees : EmployeeId, EmpName , DepartmentId

Transaction: TransactionId, EmployeeId
```

Query:

```
select distinct e.EmployeeId, e.EmpName, d.DepartmentId
    ,dbo.GetEmployeeCommissionByTransactionId(t.id) Commission
from Employees e
inner join Department d on e.DepartmentId = d.Id
left join [Transaction] t on t.EmployeeId = e.Id
where d.DepartmentId in (@departmentIds) 
--other filters
group by e.EmployeeId, e.EmpName, d.DepartmentId;
```

I have 2 more filters like below :

- MinCommission
- MaxCommission

This min and max commission would filter data based on the value return by the function '`dbo.GetEmployeeCommissionByTransactionId(t.id)`'.

Now, I know I can wrap this entire query in select statement like this :

```
select * from (My Query) as x
where x.Commission >=@minCommission
and x.Commission <=@maxCommission
```

But I have a doubt whether this will produce the correct result or not or if this is efficient too. I just want all my filters to work together in the same query to produce correct result.

Is it not possible to use the function return value in the same where clause?

Comment: How did you declare `@departmentIds`? you generally can't use a variable in an in clause unless it's a scalar value, which would yield the same results as an equals expression in this case. If it's a table variable, then you should join to it instead of using the `in` clause.

Comment: User-defined functions usually kills performance.  Using a subquery definitely does not make things worse in this case, so you might as well take that approach.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Actually there is a lot of logic inside the GetEmployeeCommissionByTransactionId function to calculate and return the commission based on Transaction Id.

Comment: It would be much better if you could convert that scalar function to an inline-table valued function, but if you cannot do that - then you can use CROSS APPLY to execute the function and return the value.  Then you can use that returned column value in the where clause.

Comment: @Jeff Can you show me how I would use outer apply and then the return column value in the where clause? Do you mind posting an answer please

Comment: Surely the commission for any particular transaction does not change once the transaction is "finalized" in some fashion. So why does it need to be computed dynamically every time a query is run that needs this information? That is your fundamental problem. Perhaps the computation is trivial and can be put into a computed column?

Comment: And is your filter definitely looking to filter on commission per transaction - unlike your previous question where you summed the commission per employee?

Answer (score 1):

Here is just an outline:

```
Select ...
  From yourTable     t
 Cross Apply (Select Commission = dbo.YourFunction(t.id)) As y
 Where y.Commission >= @minCommission
   And y.Commission <  @maxCommission;
```

Since you are filtering on the return value from the function - an outer apply is useless.

If you can rewrite the function as an inline-table valued function, you could do this:

```
Select ...
  From yourTable   t
 Cross Apply dbo.yourFunction(t.id)  y
 Where y.Commission >= @minCommission
   And y.Commission <  @maxCommission;
```

The inline-table valued function would perform much better than using a scalar function.